# What is & in return($var & 1) in PHP

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

When I was reading [this php page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php), I was not sure what & is doing in $var & 1.

```
function odd($var)
{
    // returns whether the input integer is odd
    return($var & 1);
}
```

Is it [returning a reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php)? I am not sure.

If you can explain it or direct me a php page, I will appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: PHP documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It's a bitwise-AND operation. All odd numbers have LSB (least significant bit set to 1), even numbers - 0.

So it simply "ANDs" two numbers together. For example, 5. It is represented as 101 in binary. 101 & 001 = 001 => true, so it is odd.

Comment: but 0 didn't return even numbers?,how can a function return same elements present in array

Answer (score 10):

It is performing bitwise **ANDing**.
That is a **[bitwise operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php)**

> **$a & $b**    Bits that are set in both $a and $b are set.

---

In this case, `return($var & 1);` will do a bitwise **AND** against `0000....0001` returning **1** or **0** depending on the **last bit** of `$var`.

> If the binary representation of a number ends in 0, it is even (in
> decimal).
>
> If the binary representation of a number ends in 1, it is
> odd (in decimal).

Answer (score 4):

`&` is the [bitwise and operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php). In this case it will return `1` if `$var` is odd, `0` if `$var` is even.